# Using iframe in laravel 5.2 blade template

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, laravel-5

I have a working code here

```
<iframe src="map.html" height="95%" width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now i am converting it into laravel 5.2. I want to get data from database and show that section via iframe.

How i can pass my data to `src` file?

***OTHER WAY:***

I also tried this way via AJAX/JQUERY

```
$returnHTML = view('mapcontents')->with('Map', $hs_list)->render();
 return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'map_data'=>$returnHTML));
```

But the issue is that `CSS` & `JS` code do not work in `mapcontents` because my css & js files included in main layout file.So i left this idea.

How i can fix it?

Comment: Do you want to save contents of `map.html` in your database? And then retrieve them in `src`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tried way is almost correct, you just need to call again your CSS and JS files in `mapcontents` blade. This will work fine.

Comment: This means for ->render() we always need to keep js and css on the partial view? I do not pick from parent view?

Comment: Yes its because, you are not reloading JS object which is/are applied/applying on DOm elements. Css would work, you dont need to reload CSS.
if you can re-create JS objects after `->render()` response. then you dont need to include JS and CSS files in your partial